# Form post JSON data to webservice to facilitate file download with iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, webclient

I need to call a web service which streams data back as a file download. Initially I got everything working by using a form, hidden iFrame, and a GET:

```
$("<form/>").attr({
        id: "downloadForm",
        action: webServiceURL,
        method: "GET",
        target: "downloadFrame"
    }).appendTo(downloadButton);

$("<iframe/>").attr({
    name: "downloadFrame",
    style: "visibility:hidden;display:none"
}).appendTo(downloadButton);

$('#downloadForm').submit();
$('#downloadForm').remove();
```

Now I have to change the web service call to a POST since the data could be big. So I have to send my parameters to the web service in JSON format like this:

```
{"Id1":1,"Id2":2}
```

I'm not sure how to do this. If I use $.ajax to do a POST with the parameters I don't know how to send the response to the iframe to start the file download.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you meant `var fm = $("<form/>");`? Otherwise what you are doing looks like it should work, assuming `downloadButton` exists and is part of the DOM.

Comment: You have a Typo. `id: "downloadtForm",` note the extra `t`

Comment: Thanks, updated. @Kevin, but how do I send my parameters for the POST?

Comment: with form inputs? just like you would any other normal form.

Comment: @Kevin, how do I format the form inputs to a JSON format like the one I updated in the question?

Comment: you can't do that with a normal form post via iframe, so i guess you're out of luck.

Comment: You could instead post to your own server using normal form inputs, turn them into json, then post to the target server